Multiple Knapsack with fixed weight and proprity lists
Let's say that we have

A set of $m$ knapsacks $B = \{ b_1, b_2, ..., b_m\}$

$\forall b_i \in B, \exists c_i$ which is the capacity of the knapsack $b_i$. It's an integer.

A set of $n$ items $I = \{ i_1, i_2, ..., i_n \}$

$\forall i_j \in I, \exists w_j$ which is the weight of $i_j$.

$\forall i_j \in I, w_j = 1$

$\forall i_j \in I$ and $\forall b_i \in B$, $\exists v(j,i)$ which is a function that represents the value of the item $i_j$ in the bin $b_i$.

$\forall i_j \in I, \exists P_i = \{ p_1, ..., p_w\}$ where $0 < w \le m$ and $p_i$ is one of the knapsacks $\in B$.

Let $p_x$ and $p_y \in P_j$, if $x < y$ then $p_x$ has a higher priority than $p_y$ so $i_j$ should be in $b_x$ if possible, and only in $b_y$ if being in $b_x$ isn't possible.


Let the last solution is $S = \{R_1, ..., R_m\}$ where $R_i \in S$ is the solution for knapsack $b_i \in B$, $R_i = \{r_1, ..., r_n\}$ where $r_c \in R_i$ is an item in $I$.

$i_c \in R_i$ if and only if there is $p_x \in P_c$ where $p_x = b_i$ and when $\exists p_y \in P_c$ where $y < x$ and $p_y = b_h$ then the minimum $v(e,h)$ for some item $i_e \in R_h$ must be $> v(c,h)$ and the remaining available capacity of $h$ is $0$



So, with the relaxation of $w_j$ to be fixed and identical and with adding the priority list to the multiple knapsack problem. Will this problem still be NP-complete?

I don't think the "if possible" is well-defined.  What if there is solution A that meets the first of the priority goals but not the second, and solution B that meets the second of the priority goals but not the first.  Then what is required to hold for the output?  Please [edit] your post to specify the requirement more precisely.

Updated with more details and a more precise definition of the item's value. I hope it's clearer now what I meant by "if possible."
